# JQuery - Filter Inputs by Class and Value

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, input, html-framework-7

I'm currently using AJAX to submit form values, and I need to grab values by class instead of id - the form that I'm gathering info will be used multiple times within the web application.  I'm using a combination of Framework7 and Cordova, so everything is loaded into the DOM at application launch.

So, let's say I have within the DOM these items:

```
<html>
   <div class="page1"> 
      <input type="text" class="text-foo" />
   </div>

   ....

   <div class="page1244">
      <input type="text" class="text-foo" />
   </div>
</html>
```

When displaying the form, I plan on doing this to clear out *all* of the form data:

```
$(".text-foo").val("");
```

But now I need to get the first non-blank value from these inputs.  Ideally, the JQuery selector would be something like this:

```
var valueFoo = $(".text-foo").firstNonBlankVal();
//submit the form with elite psuedocode
$.ajax(url: url + "?foo=" + escape(valueFoo));
```

Manually doing a for/each loop for each form item, and checking for each iterated object for a non-blank value seems... wasteful.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're not opposed to using [JSLINQ](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/), it can query your results (they need to be stored in an array, however, which may mitigate any benefits).

Comment: Why do you only want to submit the first value? Maybe have a look at https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Submit the first non-blank value.  Only one 'identical' form can be used at a time, and the reason why I cannot share it is because of architectual reasons; submitting serialized blank values is a waste and a hassle IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $.each is the best approach.
Following is code snippets..

```
var firstNonBlankedValue = "";
$(".text-foo").each(function(){
    if($(this).length > 0){
        firstNonBlankedValue = $(this).val();
        return;
    }
});
console.log(firstNonBlankedValue);
```

You also can check the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mhhtarnab/adw609L0/)

Comment: I was hoping to not have to iterate through, but if this is the only option I'll do it.  Thank you for posting the snippit :)